# Web scraping wikipedia data table, but from dbpedia, and examples/very basic, elementary tutorial resources to build queries

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, dbpedia

I wanted to ask about the Semantic Web part, in particular using DBpedia.  In general, what DBpedia can and can’t do?  I roughly understand the subject-verb-object model for something like DBpedia.  Practically and concretely speaking, I want to web scrape the technical data (mass, thrust, etc.) found in the [Wikipedia page of the Long March rocket family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_March_(rocket_family))

Now, as of right now (i.e., as far as I know), to find what DBpedia has (i.e., how I’m using DBpedia to find data) is that I find what I’m interested in Wikipedia, copying the last part of the URL, and copy that into DBpedia (is there any method more sophisticated than that?), [resulting in this page](http://dbpedia.org/page/Long_March_(rocket_family)).

Looking at that page, I only see links to related articles, links, and the abstract.

Other than my smaller questions above, my main question is this: so does DBpedia not have the data table that I want?

Next, could someone help me give me some tips or pointers for building a SPARQL or query string for DBpedia?  It seems to me that one wouldn't know how to build one as there's no "directory" for what could or couldn't be asked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so does dbpedia not have the data table that I want?

No, it doesn't. Usually, DBpedia gets its data from infoboxes. Your article doesn't have one, so DBpedia can't get much information out of it.

Answer (score 1):

DBpedia is an active project, and DBpedia extractors are continuing to evolve. Contributions that might help you would include adding infoboxes to Wikipedia pages, and data extractors to DBpedia. Check the [DBpedia website](http://dbpedia.org/) for info, or write to [dbpedia-discussion](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/dbpedia-discussion) to get started.

As for finding DBpedia content, there are several interfaces you can work with --

- [Faceted Browse and Search](http://dbpedia.org/fct/)
- direct [SPARQL query](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/) interface
- [iSPARQL](http://dbpedia.org/isparql/), a drag-and-drop SPARQL query builder
- [SNORQL](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/), another SPARQL query interface